# Define multiple buttons

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to define 31 buttons in one action.. Something like this :

```
    Button but[] = new Button[31];
 for(int i=1;i<32;i++)
 {
     but[i] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button0+i ---? );

 }
```

Comment: U can't.. since it takes integer as an argument.. u can't append an integer without converting it to String...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.PARENT_ID_HERE);
Button but[] = new Button[31];
for(int i=1;i<32;i++)
{
    but[i] = new Button(this);
    // set listeners and stuff
    parent.addView(but[i]);
}
```

Comment: ok.. but what you meant on Parent_ID? "Button01" or something else?

Comment: No, it's the id of the `ViewGroup` (probably a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) where you want the buttons added.

Comment: Ok..Thanks your solution helped.. But one moment.. is there a way to "distibute weights evenly"?

Answer (score 0):

In your ways is to define buttons in layout file.
You can define buttons in java activity file by addview method to add buttos to its' parent view.

Comment: I didn't understand a little... could you give me example or something?